# PHP and PDO Protecting script advice

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xss

```
$stat = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM view WHERE user_name =:user ORDER BY id DESC");
            $stat->bindValue(':user', $user);
            $stat->execute();
            $row = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
            $model=$row['model'];
```

This is script works without any problem.
Is `$model` safe or do I need to sanitize it?

Usage:

```
<span><?php echo $row['model'] ;?></span>
```

Is this safe?

Comment: No, you are open to XSS injections with this code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php Note: this is not a PDO vulnerability, your PDO/SQL is good.

Comment: good question for sure